# wso2 api manager docker storage

Tags: wso2, wso2-appm

I have setup WSO2 API Manager docker on my windows laptop and its running fine, but the API's I have deployed are getting deleted after I recreate the container again, how can persist the storage so that APIs persistence.

Answer (score 0):

API Manager stores some artifacts in the file system. You will lose these data if you recreate the container. You can attach a volume mount when running the container as follows.

```
docker run -d -v $PWD/some-direcotry/:/home/wso2carbon/wso2am-3.1.0/repository/deployment/server/ wso2am:3.1.0
```

Comment: I tried with mounting it successfully but its not persisting                                              
docker run -it -p 9443:9443 -p 8243:8243 -p 8280:8280 -d --name wso2 -v /home/docker/wso2/repository/deployment/server:/home/wso2carbon/wso2am-3.1.0/repository/deployment/server:rw docker.wso2.com/wso2am